# Matlab, an error after using fitctree function

Tags: matlab, tree, classification

I am trying to construct a decision tree. I tried using the `fitctree` function and wrote:

```
ctree = fitctree(TrainingX,TrainingY);
```

such that `TrainingX` is the input matrix and `TrainingY` is the target matrix. An error appears saying that:

> Undefined function `'fitctree'` for input arguments of type `'double'`.

I don't know what is the problem and what should I do to solve it. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it is undefined is because [`fitctree`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitctree.html) requires the Statistics Toolbox in MATLAB.  If you don't have the Statistics Toolbox, you can't use this function and you're [SOL](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=SOL).  Sorry!

Even with the Statistics Toolbox, `fitctree` is only available for recent editions of MATLAB (R2014a+).  Check the release notes on the Statistics Toolbox for more details: http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/release-notes.html.  Go to where R2014a is and fully expand out all of the facts by clicking on **Expand All**.  Where you see "Functions for classification methods and clustering", you'll see an entry for `fitctree` there.

The only option would be to upgrade your version of MATLAB to at least R2014a or above.

Good luck!

Comment: I have Matlab 2013a and you are right! It doesn't have that toolbox. How can I get Statistical Toolbox? Is it for free?

Comment: @user36729 - How did you get MATLAB?  Are you a student?  If that's the case, then you should be able to upgrade your version of MATLAB for free.  Contact your network administrator or whoever you got MATLAB from to upgrade.  If you got it by some other means, then upgrade to at least R2014a and above... however you got MATLAB before :)